# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other: - pip -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, conda, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

we are using gitlab ci/cd to integrate and deploy our projects,whenever we want to deploy our project into dev,stg,prod environments, we create fresh docker container and install all the dependencies/requirements for the project and then will deploy the code.... in this process when we run usual script, to install dependency packages and requirements we are getting the following error:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other: - pip -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --fix-missing -y \
    lsof \
    man \
    cmake \
    nano \
    supervisor \
    net-tools \
    pv \
    multitail \
    bsdmainutils \
    blender \
    texlive-base \
    texlive-latex-base \
    texlive-latex-recommended \
    texlive-latex-extra \
    xmlsec1 \
    libgl1-mesa-glx

RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux- 
   x86_64.sh \
     && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp \
     && rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

RUN conda install -n base conda -y \
    && conda install -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce -c jf 
    pythonocc-core -y
```